# Drupal Commerce permission

Tags: commerce, users

I've just noticed that the anonymous user can add staff to the cart but they cannot see the block. Also, I've create a display content view and anonymous users cannot see it.

I've tried to find the right permission but there is not a permission tutorial.

Is anyone has got experience with it?

I would like to leave anonymous users use the cart but then login once they have to pay.

How do i get it?

The problem comes when I add, in the view, the relationship with the product.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Commerce Checkout Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect) will help with getting users to login/register before they pay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two places that come to mind on the Permissions page (/admin/people/permissions) are:

- Under **Checkout**, look for *Access checkout*
- Under **Order**, look for *View own orders of any type*

Comment: I've reset all the permission but still does not work... What could I do.. we have already uploaded the contents...

Answer (score 2):

I've just noticed that the problem comes when I add, in the view, the relationship with the product. Anonymous users cannot see it.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to the view, under advanced make sure that SQL is NOT rewritten. This is a common reason why views won't work for Anon users.

Comment: Query setting if you're still lost.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the "Require this relationship" option on the product relationship in the view, saved, and now the view shows items to anonymous users.